# Why is the sign character accepted in the function definition?

Tags: r, function

Due to a typo I found out this code works [note the repeated `-` in the 2nd line]

```
foo <- function()
-------------------------
{
  1
}
```

Calling `foo()` returns `-1`. The number of `-` determines if the returned value is positive or negative [odd number returns a negative number].

I didn't find anything regarding this R function definition so I am now asking why is this allowed and what is the purpose of this.

Even the official [R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf) doesn't mention this at all. Any idea?

A note: `invisible(1)` doesn't work. The output is not suppressed when there is a sign character before the opening `{`.

Comment: That's an odd one, I've never seen (nor would I have thought to even try it. If you think about it, `{ }` is really just a block of zero or more R expressions, and the last expression is preserved/returned. For instance `{1;2;3}` "returns" `3`. From there, a leading `-` will just "negate" the last statement, so `-{1;2;3}` returns `-3`, etc. In this case, since you're returning a number (or number-like class), it works fine. If you instead did `foo <- function() ---{"a"}`, it will fail.

Comment: (Since R allows multiple `-` signs, so `----2` is `2`, having an arbitrary number of minus-signs before the code block should make more sense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tripped on the strange allowances of R's syntax rules for function bodies.

Since the [syntax of functions in R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Syntax-and-examples) allow for any expression after the argument list, usually R functions provide a list of expressions surrounded by `{}`. This is sometimes known in other languages as an expression "block." In R, the "evaluation value" of a block is the evaluation value of the last expression in the block.

- If `-1` is a valid expression, then `-{1}` is a valid expression as well.

`-` is also the unary negation operator, and it is repeatable in R. Therefore:

```r
1 = 1
-1 != -1
--1 == 1
----1 == 1
-----1 == -1
```

So the evaluation goes:

```r
foo <- function() ------------------------- {1}
foo <- function() ------------------------- 1
foo <- function() -1
```

And due to R's syntax rules, you could as easily go:

```r
foo <- function() -1
```

Comment: OK, of course as I am calling it in my question the `sign` character and not `hyphen`. So I am aware of the `sign` character functionality. I am asking why can be placed a `sign` character before the opening `{`. It works also with a `+` but this doesn't change of course the sign.

Comment: CinchBlue, this is not really addressing the `{...}` code-block portion of why PeterVARGA's code actually works (it's a seemingly minor but critical thing). See my comments. Your point of repeated `-` is appropriate, if you add braces around your first `1` I think it'll wrap this up.

Comment: He edited the question, so I needed to edit my answer

Comment: I didn't edit the my question, I added only the note regarding the `invisible()` fact. See the edit history.

Comment: `function() -1` this type of function syntax is commonly used in `lapply` functions. example `lapply(df1, function(x) tail(unique(x)))`

Comment: I accepted and upvoted your answer as your last edit answered my question. It looks to me like a _feature_ of the R parser.